# Qual è il significato di "placarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: verbs, meaning

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Le nuvole confondevano il vento, smembrandosi in corsa e il vento correva e ringhiava da cane pastore per tenerle unite in branco. Verso sera tutte le forme possibili **si placavano** in linee di rosso dove il sole scendeva e chiamava tutto il cielo a rompersi e a sparire.

Ho cercato il verbo "placare" in parecchi dizionari. Tuttavia, non riesco a capirne il senso nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Comment: Come quando il mare agitato si placa e diventa liscio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato significa che le nuvole, quasi fossero pecore di un gregge, si muovevano continuamente e alla sera si placavano, cioè si allineavano in gruppo come se stessero tornando all'ovile.

Come correttamente fatto notare da @egreg è "come quando il mare agitato si placa e diventa liscio"

> [placarsi](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/placare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) v. intr. pron. 1. [diventare calmo e tranquillo: *era
>   arrabbiato ma ora si sta placando*] ≈ calmarsi, quietarsi,